# (pdksh) Looping through n files and store their dates in array

Tags: arrays, shell, scripting, pdksh

Using **pdksh**

`stat()` command is unavailable on system.

**I need to loop through the amount of files found and store their dates in an array**. `$COMMAND` stores the number of files found in `$location` as can be seen below.

Can someone help me please?

```
COMMAND=`find $location -type f | wc -l`
CMD_getDate=$(find $location -type f | xargs ls -lrt | awk '{print $6} {print $7}')
```

Comment: OK, what do you want the final array to look like?  Just an array of dates with no way to figure out which filename goes with which date?  And what sort of dates - strings like `Tue Jun  2 08:58:06 EDT 2015`?  time_t values like `1433249886`?  ISO 8601, like `2015-06-02T12:58:06Z`? I assume you want the mtime (as opposed to the atime or ctime)?

Comment: If I would have 2 arrays then I would be able to know. This is because they will be sorted beforehand no?
I just need to save the date Jun 2 for example .. then I do the same for filename, time etc..

Answer (score 0):

Well, first, you don't need to do the `wc`.  The size of the array will tell you how many there are. Here's a simple way to build an array of dates and names (designed for pdksh; there are better ways to do it in AT&T ksh or bash):

```
set -A files 
set -A dates
find "$location" -type f -ls |&
while read -p inum blocks symode links owner group size rest; do 
  set -A files "${files[@]}" "${rest##* }"
  set -A dates "${dates[@]}" "${rest% *}"
done
```

Here's one way to examine the results:

```
print "Found ${#files[@]} files:"
let i=0
while (( i < ${#files[@]} )); do
  print "The file '${files[i]}' was modified on ${dates[i]}."
  let i+=1
done
```

This gives you the full date string, not just the month and day.  That might be what you want - the date output of `ls -l` (or `find -ls`) is variable depending on how long ago the file was modified.  Given these files, how does your original format distinguish between the modification times of `a` and `b`?

```
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 mjreed  staff  0 Feb  3  2014 a
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 mjreed  staff  0 Feb  3 04:05 b
```

As written, the code above would yields this for the above directory with `location`=`.`:

```
Found 2 files:
The file './a' was modified on Feb  3  2014.
The file './b' was modified on Feb  3 00:00.
```

It would help if you indicated what the actual end goal is..

Comment: I don't think my system allows using of typeset -a as it says '0403-010 A specified flag is not valid for this command.' ... Also for the array i can see the dates and filenames but as you said they are gone by the time the loop exited.

Comment: OK, you're using pdksh, not AT&T ksh.  check my edit.

Comment: Thanks for your help but when inputting the block of code of set -A etc .. i get the following - 
[1] +  Done                    find "$location" -type f -ls |&

Comment: that's to be expected at the end of the loop.  The coprocess job terminated.